# sending (and not replying) sms from twilio using AWS Lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, twilio

I have set up a webhook to some python code on an aws lambda which can receive a text sent to a twilio number, and based on that text, REPLY with different messages.

Its easy, I simply return some specific XML from the lambda_handler(event, context) function.

What I can't do is, based on the body of the text, initiate a NEW text to person B. I'd like something like this,

1. Person A sends SMS to Twilio# with the sms body of 'A'
2. Twilio Number sends SMS to Person B with the sms body 'A says hello'

I can work out all the logic, I just can't figure out how to send a txt other than as a return statement from my lambda_handler function. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You just need a To attribute:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/twiml/message#attributes-to

The 'to' attribute takes a valid phone number as an argument. Twilio will send the message to the number provided. If no 'to' attribute is provided, Twilio will send the message as a reply to the current sender.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Message to="+15555551212">
        Store Location: 123 Easy St.
    </Message>
</Response>
```